# How to track only file image.png on Apache2 server

Tags: apache, logging, apache2

I have Apache 2.4.29 on the server. 
I wrote a script sending requests to the server randomly (in the scheduled queue) to one

```
  domain.org/pixel.png?variable=value
```

address.

This domain is configured in apache in sites-available this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/user/site/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/axonite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/axonite-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have to check if requests landed successfully and variable passed correctly.

How can I configure logs to track ONLY requests to this pixel.png file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write a simple script to parse the info from logs using grep?

For example: `grep "image.png" ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/axonite-access.log` and then direct the output to a new log file.